# Read system call returning zero bytes though the socket is ready for read

Tags: c, sockets, unix, unix-socket

I have a client-server application in c which is using unix domain socket.

Here server is reading a integer from client.  Client successfully sends a 4 bytes to server.

but at the server end I could see that the read system call is reading 0 bytes from socket.

I am pretty much sure that the data is available for read on server since the select call before read operation is succeeding.

Any idea why this is happenning?

Comment: please create a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe add parentheses to the `if(rc=read(fd,buff, sizeof buff) == 0)` ? ;-)

Comment: > tcp client-server application in c which is using unix domain socket

This does not make sense. TCP is one protocol and lives in AF_INET address family, so can be on top of IP.
Unix Domain socket is another address family.

You cannot have TCP on top of Unix Domain socket.

Comment: `I am pretty much sure that the` ... error is in the part of the code that you did not show us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any code, it's hard to guess what exactly happens, but `select()` succeeding does not necessarily mean that some data are ready to be read.

`select()` just makes the promise that if you try **one** read from this file-descriptor you will not be blocked.
The reason might be any of these:

- the kernel stores in an internal buffer some data to be delivered through the file-descriptor you read (it's what you are expecting here),
- **or** the other end of the file-descriptor is closed, then no new data will ever be delivered (the EOF you observe),
- **or** the file-descriptor is in an invalid state for a read operation and any read attempt will immediately fail (see `errno` after read).

Comment: Thanks @prog-fh . Apparently it comes out that second case was being hit by program.