# Select returns success even if connection is terminated by peer socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I am having trouble understanding the use of select system call. As per [select documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) , select will return after timeout or socket is ready for I/O operation. What does it mean by `socket is ready for I/O operation` ?

```
  received_len  = 0
  do {
       /* There is only one fd in readfds */
       rv = select(fd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, timeout)
       if (rv < 0){
           /*socket select failed.*/
           break
       }else if (rv == 0){
           /*socket timeout.*/
           break
       }else
           /* Go for reading */
           readbytes = read(fd, (buf + received_len), (expected_len - received_len))
           if (readbytes < 0)
           {
               /*read fail*/
               break
           }
           received_len += readbytes; 
           
   }while(received_len < expected_len)
```

I though select will timed out when peer socket connection closes. but after closing peer connection select returns 1 and read happens on socket. Then read call returns 0 (Which basically means peer terminated). I thought select will be timed out since the socket is not still ready for read operation but that is not happenning.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66135105/11527076) to your question. 0 is a valid result for read (meaning EOF). select does not make the promise that you will obtain some bytes when reading; just that the **next** read operation won't be blocked, whatever the reason.

Comment: In the example you gave, you consider the read failure as a valid case; why the EOF case would be so different? (I would just write `if (readbytes <= 0)` in order to break in both cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) you cited in the question

> readfds
>
> The file descriptors in this set are watched to see if
> they are ready for reading.  A file descriptor is ready
> for reading if a read operation will not block; in
> particular, a file descriptor is also ready on end-of-
> file.